# Why are my UIView layer properties not being set when called within initWIthCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiview, interface-builder

I have a custom View class built which subclasses UIView.

This view is loaded through a nib file in the ViewController via:

```
[[NSBundle main] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
```

Inside **MyCustomView.h** (which correctly hooked up in IB as the Main Views class)
I have some subview properties linked:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate> {
....
@public

UIView *backgroundLayer; // a subview of the Main View inside the nib
....
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *backgroundLayer;
```

This outlet is properly connected within Interface Builder.

Inside **MyCustomView.m** I have the following implementation:

```
#import <quartzcore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation MyCustomView

@synthesize backgroundLayer;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
   if (self) {
      ....
      self.backgroundLayer.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0f;
      self.backgroundLayer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
      self.backgroundLayer.layer.maskToBounds = YES;
      ....
   }
```

**NONE** of those backgroundLayer.layer settings are being applied. When I run in simulator the custom view appears exactly how it appears in the NIB without any of those mods? What am I missing? Am I making the calls in the incorrect place?

Comment: Upon further examination it appears that **backgroundLayer** is still NULL when I'm tying to modify it within __initWithCoder__.

Comment: **UPDATE** Can we delete questions? Just discovered _-(void)awakeFromNib_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct answer to this issue was to use the method :

```
 -(void)awakeFromNib {
    ......
 }
```

Comment: What is the solution if I am manually encoding a UIView without a nib?