# Where do you set a subview's layer properties? Why not in the initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview, custom-controls

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` (for this example, let's just say the subclass is `MyViewCell`) which has an Nib file associated to it `MyViewCell.xib`. The nib contains a `UITableViewCell` with one subview `UIView` (named `cardContainer`) that's simply a rectangle with a blue background. I want to add a drop shadow around the `UIView`, so I added set the layer properties in the `-initWithCoder` call:

```
@implementation MyViewCell


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initView];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) initView
{
    UIBezier Path*shadowPath =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];        
    [self.cardContainer.layer setShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.cardContainer.layer setShadowOpacity: 0.8];
    [self.cardContainer.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
    [self.cardContainer.layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(2.0,2.0)];
    view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}


@end
```

The problem I'm having is that these layer properties aren't being drawn. If I call the `-initView` call within `awakeFromNib` or `drawRect` it's drawn as expected. My question: why doesn't my original code work? Where should I be calling `initView`? Is there some view lifecycle? I understand that the `initWithCoder` doesn't have the outlets connected, but it didn't crash at runtime.

I read through [Apple documentation around Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) and searched through the SO questions without finding an answer. I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171448/why-are-my-uiview-layer-properties-not-being-set-when-called-within-initwithcode), but again doesn't explain.

Comment: try putting it in cellForRowatIndexpath after initialising your view

Comment: @suhit I feel that the shadow code should be contained within the custom view. I could be reusing it in other view controllers

Comment: can you post the code in `cellForRowatIndexpath`??

Comment: @johnMa the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't do anything interesting. In my `viewDidLoad` call, I register the associated nib file to the `UITableView`, and in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I just call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with a static identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I found a better way to do this ,just add some runtime attributes for your subview `cardContainer`

like this [image]

no more code in .m file anymore.

**EDIT:**

From:[NSNibAwaking Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000425-BABGDAEF)

> Important:  Because the order in which objects are instantiated from an archive is not guaranteed, your initialization methods should not send messages to other objects in the hierarchy. Messages to other objects can be sent safely from within awakeFromNib—by which time it’s assured that all the objects are unarchived and initialized (though not necessarily awakened, of course).

Comment: While your solution 'works', this doesn't completely answer the question of why my original code didn't work

Comment: After reading [NSNibWeaking Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000425-BABGDAEF),I think your view had been reestablish during the nib wakeing process. Have a look.

Comment: The `NSNibAwakeningProtocol` link was really helpful, thanks. If you want to edit your answer talking about the NSNibAwakeningProtocol, I'll go ahead and accept it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this,

```
self.cardContainer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: you don't need the border for a shadow