# Changing button text is not working iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

I've dragged a button using storyboard and created IBoutlet for it in .h file also synthesised it.

Now i'm trying to change the text of the button but it is not working for me.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) 
    {
        configDetails *updatedConfig=[[configDetails alloc]init];
        [updatedConfig setAllItemstext:@" Go to AllItems"];
        [updatedConfig setAboutUstext:@"Text for AboutUs button"];
        [updatedConfig setHomeScreenTitleColor:@"Yellow"];

        NSString *newtext=[updatedConfig aboutUstext];
        NSLog(@"%@",newtext);
        [aboutUs setTitle:[updatedConfig aboutUstext] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [allItems setTitle:[updatedConfig allItemstext] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

return self;
}
```

Comment: Is the code above actually being executed? Have you tried adding a breakpoint?

Comment: Is `[updatedConfig allItemstext]` getting the value?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya ya It prints the giventext

Comment: @Chancy I tried it didn't work

Comment: try to set the title in viewDidLoad

Comment: Set your title's in loadView or viewdidload method.

Comment: Make yourself a favor and begin the class names with a capital letter.

Comment: have you connected the IBOutlet to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set your IBOutlet properties in `initWithCoder` method .

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626203/where-do-you-set-a-subviews-layer-properties-why-not-in-the-initwithcoder?answertab=votes#tab-top) about this

Answer (score 1):

Try like this write your code into `viewDidAppear`:-

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  configDetails *updatedConfig=[[configDetails alloc]init];
    [updatedConfig setAllItemstext:@" Go to AllItems"];
    [updatedConfig setAboutUstext:@"Text for AboutUs button"];
    [updatedConfig setHomeScreenTitleColor:@"Yellow"];

    NSString *newtext=[updatedConfig aboutUstext];
    NSLog(@"%@",newtext);
    [aboutUs setTitle:[updatedConfig aboutUstext] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [allItems setTitle:[updatedConfig allItemstext] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```