# setTitleColor:forState in UIButton subclass initWithCoder not setting color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have subclassed a UIButton that I have included in a custom .xib file and I am trying to set the title colour for the button via the `initWithCoder` method for each state. Currently, I have this:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if(self) {
    self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor navigationLabelColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
  return self;
}
```

However, the title colour is not changed but the edge insets are. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I should add, the custom xib is for a different element, but there are several instances of this button in that xib.

Comment: did you try with any other color?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes I did. `[UIColor greenColor]` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Many developer will be agree on not subclassing the UIButton as its pretty complex so you can try other options

Comment: @Retro Successful subclassing of `UIButton` depends on your needs, it is not always inappropriate.

Comment: I don't suppose the button is "selected" in Interface Builder?

Comment: you can not custom ib element in `initWithCoder` , see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626203/where-do-you-set-a-subviews-layer-properties-why-not-in-the-initwithcoder?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @johnMa Yes, your setting runtime attributes in IB is great but that does not provide a solution to all requirements. There are situations where `UIButton` can be subclassed, add functionality and work correctly.

Comment: I mean the title color didn't change because you set it in `initWithCoder` method.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing UIButton is not straight forward due to `UIButtonType` which seems to default to `UIButtonTypeCustom` for simple subclassing. Changing the frame/bounds seems to work fine but some other aspects don't.

Personally I have successfully subclassed for my needs which used `UIButtonTypeCustom` and mainly added background image stretching.

You man need to find another method to accomplish your needs or delve deeper into subclassing UIButton.

Due a search on subclassing UIButton and you will find a substantial amount of information including comments saying that basically not to. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202493/451475).

Comment: Hey Zaph, thanks for your reply and sorry it took so long to get back to you. The issue I was having was that the title is an attributed string, so to change the properties of an attributed string you must call: `setAttributedTitle:forState:`. Thanks nonetheless.